# Perl POD coverage for scripts and tests (not modules)

Tags: perl, code-coverage, perl-pod

Is there a way to measure POD coverage for scripts (e.g. `*.pl`)?

I can measure documentation coverage for *packages* using `Pod::Coverage` and `Test::Pod::Coverage`, but I cannot measure it for *scripts*, because `Pod::Coverage` and the underlying `Devel::Symdump` use `require` to inspect the content of the package, which fails due to the lack of a `.pm` file.

Is there a way to work around this?

(I have to have POD documentation in the `.pl` files, so moving everything into a module and documenting it there is not a good solution for me. Wherever I could do that, it's already done that way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pod::Coverage loads (executes) the module to let it create subs and such. You would have to prevent your .pl from running normally somehow.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
...
main(@ARGV) if !$ENV{NO_RUN};
1; # For do()
```

But once you've done that, it's easy because you tell Pod::Coverage which package to examine (`package`) and which file to examine (`pod_from`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 1;

use Pod::Coverage qw( );

{
    package the_script;
    local $ENV{NO_RUN} = 1;
    do "script.pl" or die $@;
}

my $pc = Pod::Coverage->new(
   package  => 'the_script',
   pod_from => 'script.pl',
);

# P::C expects "require the_script;" to succeed.
$INC{"the_script.pm"} = 1;

my $coverage = $pc->coverage();
die $pc->why_unrated()
   if !defined($coverage);

ok($coverage)
   or diag("Not covered: ".join(', ', $pc->naked()));

1;
```

Tested.

Comment: I like the idea, I'll try it out, and report back.I'd upvote, but I'm too much of a newcomer at the moment... :)

Comment: The coverage is `undef`, and the reason reported by `$pc->why_unrated()` is `no public symbols defined`. I encountered this error also with modules: there I had to change `package Bar` to `package Foo::Bar`, and that solved the problem. But I'm not quite sure how to change `package the_script` in this case. I'll give it another go tomorrow...

Comment: genius! Works like a charm! Augmenting all the scripts with the `$ENV{NO_RUN}` check is a one-time pain I'm willing to accept. Thanks for your quick help! And I actually learned some new stuff about `do` today, so another +1 for that! :)

Comment: Make it main(@ARGV) unless caller

Comment: @jira, There are instances where that gives a false positive. Aside from the obvious impossibility of launching your script via `do`, I mean. I can't remember what exactly, though. Maybe it's when the script is run in the debugger? I'll keep the current code; it works just as well and has no downsides.

Comment: @jira, @ikegami, @brian-d-foy: I checked `perl -d script.pl`, and indeed, `caller()` returns `DB/usr/share/perl/5.14/perl5db.pl640` inside the debugger. However, it seems to be working well with `do`.

Answer (score 4):

Make your program a modulino. That's [what ikegami is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12586646/8817), but he makes you set an environment variable.

```
run(@ARGV) unless caller;
```

Once your program is really a module with some default behavior, you can use module tools on it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the whole modulino concept in the short run, as I have to keep the executable `.pl` files for historical reasons. But I will use it for new scripts for sure and start to rework older scripts as I happen to touch them.

Comment: Sure you can use it. The file is still a program and you can name it whatever you like, but you can also load it like a module.

Comment: I read through http://www.drdobbs.com/scripts-as-modules/184416165 again, and indeed it will be simpler to take it into use than I first realized. Thanks for nudging me, and not giving up! :)

Comment: however, I'm still leaning towards @ikegami's environment variable based solution due to `caller()` returning `true` under a debugger (at least `perl -d`). Do you have a trick for that up in your sleeves too? :)